# Table image is removed after pasting

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

```
Function FnAddTableToWordDocument()
Dim intNoOfRows
Dim intNoOfColumns
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objRange
Dim objTable

intNoOfRows = 14
intNoOfColumns = 2

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    Set objRange = objDoc.Range
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("qr_code_1")).Select
    Selection.copy
    objWord.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdPasteDefault)

    objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns
    Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)

    objTable.Borders.Enable = Disable
    objTable.Rows.Item(1).Height = 0
For i = 1 To intNoOfRows
For j = 1 To intNoOfColumns
        objTable.Cell(i, j).Range.Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value
        objTable.Rows.Item(i).Height = 13
```

In the code above i am copying an image from a spreadsheet into a word document what has just been created and then adding my table.
The problem is the instant i add the table the entire image gets deleted it doesn't matter where when or how it just refuses to be on the same document as the table.
I have been going nuts this is my first time using word documents to save as separate data and i feel like im missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.tables.add) states:

> The table replaces the range, if the range isn't collapsed.

Try replacing the lines

```
    objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns
    Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
```

with these line (updated following comments)

```
    objDoc.Shapes(1).ConvertToInlineShape
    objDoc.Range.Select
    objWord.Selection.Collapse (0)
    Set objTable = objDoc.Tables.Add(objWord.Selection.Range, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns)
```

Another approach is to paste the shape after adding the table.

Comment: This worked but now the QR Code is below the table. How can i swap the order? It also seems that i cant set the border or row height right now

Comment: Updated my answer. Not sure why you can't set heights/borders.

Comment: Fixed the bordering issue. When i try your snippet i get an out of bounds error